# Cookie field is missing at the redirected path when sameSite option is enabled(ExpessJs)

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

```
route1:
  res.setCookie('field1', 'value1', { sameSite: true })
  res.setCookie('field2', 'value2')

  res.redirect('/route2')

route2:
  const { field1, field2 } = req.cookies
  // field1 === undefined
  // field2 === 'value2'
```

Any idea how to pass cookie fields with sameSite option true to redirected path using express?

Comment: have you installed the cookieParser

Comment: Yes, I have. I don't suppose parser is the issue because the field doesn't appear in the cookie at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this is some sort of race condition issue on the browser side, not ExpressJS. Response sending redirect status with set-cookie header is fine. However, request header sent immediately after to the redirected path somehow omits the cookie field with the same-site option true even though I'm redirecting to the same site. I don't know if this is expected behavior but had to work around this in a not quite happy way by adding an intermediate screen.